# How to call a function passing only one optional argument?

Tags: vba

If my function looks like

```
function(optional byval string1 as String,optional byval string2 as String,optional byval string3 as String )
```

And I only want to call the function by supplying `string3` by entering `"=function(string3)"` in cell, how can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible in one of two ways...

1. Call the routine and identify which optional parameter is being used by "skipping" unusued parms:

```
Function MyFunc(optional a as integer, _
                optional b as integer, _
                optional c as integer) as double
    MyFunc = c * 3.14159
End Function

=MyFunc(,,12)   <== called as UDF on worksheet or in VBA module
```

2. Code your function with an argument list:

```
Function MyFunc(args() As Variant) As Double
    Dim numberOfArgs As Integer
    Dim arg As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim answer As Double
    numberOfArgs = UBound(args)
    i = 1
    For Each arg In args
        Debug.Print "arg(" & i & ") = " & arg
        answer = Int(arg) * 3.14159
        i = i + 1
    Next arg
    MyFunc = answer
End Function

Sub test1()
    Dim parms() As Variant
    ReDim parms(1 To 3)
    'parms(1) = ??
    'parms(2) = ??
    parms(3) = 21
    Debug.Print MyFunc(parms)
End Sub
```